# Querying Last Entries group by DeviceId

Tags: mysql, database, distinct

I have the database table **logs** as the following:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/16e974703a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/16e974703a.jpg)

I would like to extract the last entry of device, pollDate, status.  For eg.

deviceId,         pollDate,              status

1,         2010-95-06 10:53:28,          1

3,         2010-95-06 10:26:28,          1

---

I tried to run the following query but the distinct only selects the first records, not the latest

```
SELECT DISTINCT deviceId, pollDate, status
FROM logs
GROUP By deviceId
ORDER BY pollDate DESC
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5d181103f8.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5d181103f8.jpg)

So, could you please help me to extract the latest entries from the table?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `(deviceID, poll_date)` is unique, you can do the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  deviceid, MAX(poll_date) AS md
        FROM    logs
        GROUP BY
                deviceid
        ) q
JOIN    logs l
ON      l.deviceid = q.deviceid
        AND l.poll_date = q.md
```